# How to prevent make from echo'ing commands to the console?

Tags: makefile

I'm using the following Makefile with GNU make. As you can see, I prepended an `@` to the lines which call g++, to prevent them from being echo'ed to the console.

However, the g++ commands are still echo'ed. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

I have an almost identical Makefile for a C project, and it works correctly..

Thanks!

```
# for portability.
SHELL   = /bin/sh
CXX     = g++

# compile flags.
CXXFLAGS = -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -march=native -O2 \
           -fwhole-program -flto

TARGET  = program
MANPAGE = program.8
SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo src/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
VERSION = 0.1-beta

# installation paths.
PREFIX  = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR  = $(PREFIX)/sbin
MANDIR  = $(PREFIX)/share/man/man8

# standard targets.
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "[LD] $@"
        @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

man:
        @(cd man; gzip < $(MANPAGE) > $(MANPAGE).gz)

install: $(TARGET) man
        @install -D -m 755 $(TARGET) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
        @install -D -m 744 man/$(MANPAGE).gz $(MANDIR)/$(MANPAGE).gz

install-strip: $(TARGET) man
        @install -D -m 755 -s $(TARGET) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
        @install -D -m 744 man/$(MANPAGE).gz $(MANDIR)/$(MANPAGE).gz

uninstall:
        @$(RM) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
        @$(RM) $(MANDIR)/$(MANPAGE).gz

clean:
        @$(RM) $(OBJECTS)

distclean: clean
        @$(RM) $(TARGET)
        @(cd man; $(RM) $(MANPAGE).gz)

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
        @echo "[CXX] $<"
        @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: all man install install-strip uninstall clean distclean
```

Comment: Do you have any `src/*.h` files? If you do not, built-in rule for .o files will take precedence. Using `wildcard` instead of `shell` should solve that.

Comment: Using `make -s` or adding a line `.SILENT:` would both suppress all the output from `make`.  However, the leading `@` markers should do that too.  I personally don't like makefiles that don't show, or have a mechanism to show, exactly what is being executed because it is hard to debug when something goes wrong.  That being the case, I don't use either `-s` or `.SILENT:` on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks @Banthar, I was testing the Makefile without any headers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would really help if you'd provided the actual command you run and a sample of the incorrect output you see (plus a few lines of context before and after).

Do you see both the `[CXX] src/xxx.cpp` *and* the compile line?  There's no way that can happen given the makefile you've provided.  If you see only the compile line, that means that make is deciding to not use your pattern rule and is instead using its own build-in pattern rule.  You'll need to use `make -d` to see why make gives up on your pattern rule.

As an aside, you can use `$(wildcard src/*.cpp)` rather than `$(shell echo src/*.cpp)`, and you should always use `:=` not `=` when assigning the results of a shell function (or wildcard or any function which is computationally expensive) unless there's a specific reason to defer expansion.